# Ensure whitespaces between footnote numbers, citation numbers, etc...

Tags: footnotes

Is there a way to ensure that footnote numbers and similar don't stick together in the final document (because I forgot a manual space between them?

Example:
Instead of

```
asdf\footnote{a}\footnote{b}
```

which produces

> asdf12

I want:

> asdf 1 2

Is there a package that does this? (Or even some Grep-Magic?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
```

See `multiple` option of `footmisc` package.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/footmisc.html

Comment: It would be great if you could post the full explanation, [not just the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/155585).

Comment: @Hendrik: I added the code. There is almost no difference. Usage is simple, well documented and easy to understand.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44165/compressing-consecutive-footnote-marks