# Compressing consecutive footnote marks

Tags: footnotes

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`footnoterange`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnoterange)

I have a series of consecutively numbered footnotes that appear as (1,2,...,N). I would like these to be condensed to a hyphenated series consisting of only the first and last member of the series (1–N), analogous to the behavior of the `cite` and `natbib` packages for [consecutively-numbered bibliographic references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3874/10127). I have loaded the package `footmisc` to enable proper display of consecutive footnotes, but this package appears to only support comma delineation (and not hyphenation) of footnote lists (cf. [`footmisc` manual](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf)).

**Edit:** I have added three MWEs to make my intentions clear. MWE1 shows the default LaTeX behavior. MWE2 shows the improvements afforded by invocation of `\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}`. MWE3 shows the desired outcome.

MWE1 (default):

[image]

MWE2 (footmisc):

[image]

MWE3 (desired):

[image]

The source codes are included here:

MWE1 (default):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=4.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
This text bears a multiplicity of footnotes%
\footnote{Lorum}\footnote{ipsum}\footnote{dolor}%
\footnote{sit}\footnote{amet,}\footnote{consectetur}%
\footnote{adipisicing}\footnote{elit}.%
\end{document}
```

MWE2 (footmisc):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=4.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
This text bears a multiplicity of footnotes%
\footnote{Lorum}\footnote{ipsum}\footnote{dolor}%
\footnote{sit}\footnote{amet,}\footnote{consectetur}%
\footnote{adipisicing}\footnote{elit}.%
\end{document}
```

MWE3 (desired):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=4.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
This text bears a multiplicity of footnotes$^{1\textrm{--}8}.$%
\footnotetext[1]{Lorum}\footnotetext[2]{ipsum}\footnotetext[3]{dolor}%
\footnotetext[4]{sit}\footnotetext[5]{amet,}\footnotetext[6]{consectetur}%
\footnotetext[7]{adipisicing}\footnotetext[8]{elit}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to give the references to a range of footnotes, the `footnoterange` environment of the [`footnoterange`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footnoterange) package is the obvious choice:

```
\documentclass{article}
% load hyperref or footmisc or other packages here
% hyperref-option hyperfootnotes=true or =false as you like
% if you use the cleverref package:
%  it must be loaded after hyperref, never before hyperref
\usepackage{footnoterange}
\begin{document}
This text bears a multiplicity of footnotes%
\begin{footnoterange}%
\footnote{Lorum}\footnote{ipsum}\footnote{dolor}%
\footnote{sit}\footnote{amet,}\footnote{consectetur}%
\footnote{adipisicing}\footnote{elit}%
\end{footnoterange}%
 which are referenced as one footnoterange.
\end{document}
```

Use the `footnoterange*` environment, if you use the `hyperref` package with option
`hyperfootnotes=true` but without wanting hyperlinked footnotes.
[As for a truly automatic solution without the need for `\begin{footnoterange}` and
`\end{footnoterange}`: Sorry! That's *too* tricky. See also 
[Incompatibility between footmisc-option multiple and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40072/6865) asking for more automatic footnote-handling.]

Comment: Thanks Stephen. The code you have posted triggers an undefined control sequence error pertaining to `cref` macros. I believe this is because my `cleveref` version (0.14.2, 22/09/2009) is dated, as Mico has suggested. I will have to upgrade this package and try again.

Comment: Your code is certainly a step in the correct direction. How can I insert a new line between the footnotes? I routinely encounter the caveat that something will not work with `hyperref`. Do you know why this is? Presumably the `hyperref` package maintainers are aware of this and are trying to fix it (?). Or maybe it is an intrinsic and unavoidable problem associated with hyperlinking, and cannot be resolved by source code alterations (?). Why is your code incompatible with `hyperref`? What is the function of the code you inserted from `hyperref` in the custom `rangefootnote` macro? Thanks!

Comment: @user001: It did not work with hyperref because of a stupid mistake in my code: hyperref must be loaded *before* cleveref but I used it *afterwards*! Now corrected. About the code-lines of hyperref: The package uses its own counter for footnotes, which is not increased automatically when using `\footnotetext`. Further its Readme says: "The footnote support is rather limited. It is beyond the scope to use \footnotemark and \footnotetext out of order or reusing \footnotemark. Here you can either disable hyperref’s footnote support by "hyperfootnotes=false" or" ...  (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation) ...  "fiddle with internal macros". And that is what the code does, thereby getting the numeration/hyperlinks right.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to place newline characters between successive footnotes?

Comment: Using the `para` option with the `footmisc` package prints the footnotes in one "paragraph". Without that option, each footnote begins in a new line/paragraph.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. Are you able to make your code compatible with the option that disables hyperfootnotes (i.e., `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`)? I sometimes use `hyperref` without `hyperfootnotes`, but when I included this option, the document would not compile. Thanks!

Comment: @user001: I changed the code (added check for `hyperfootnotes= true or false`). Please test whether it suites your needs. (I did not define a `\labelcrefrange*` yet, because that would be still more complicated.)

Comment: Great, thanks Stephen. Your code is very useful. What is the `\labelcrefrange*` you speak about?

Comment: `\ref*` (or `\pageref*` and similar) are used when hyperref is loaded but the respective reference shall not be hyperlinked. The code as it is now does the following: hyperref & hyperfootnotes=true -> hyperlink; hyperref & hyperfootnotes=false -> no hyperlink; no hyperref -> no hyperlink (naturally); what is not covered is hyperref & hyperfootnotes=true but nevertheless no hyperlink. With hyperref & hyperfootnotes=true all footnotes get hyperlinks, and it is not possible to use `\labelcrefrange*` to have one reference which is not hyperlinked. (Probably this issue is more a hypothetical one.)

Comment: but now solved with the `footnoterange*` environment.

Comment: Wow, impressive -- I think it's a great contribution to LaTeX! And it is as automatic as it needs to be. Thanks, Stephen. I've downloaded your package already. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you look into the [cleveref](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package and its commands `\crefrange` and `\cref`. The former commands takes two arguments, the first and last label of a range of items to be cross-referenced; with the second command, you just specify all labels that are to be cross-referenced, and the package will sort and, if possible, compress the list automatically. The arguments of the `\cref` command needn't even be in any order.

The following MWE illustrates how this may be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc} % since you mention that you use this package
\usepackage{cleveref}
  \newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{--}      % default: " to "
  \newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and } % default: " and ", i.e., without the comma
\begin{document}
\section{Hey, let's create some footnotes}
Once\footnote{A \label{fn:A}} upon\footnote{B \label{fn:B}} a\footnote{C \label{fn:C}} time,\footnote{D \label{fn:D}} there\footnote{E \label{fn:E}} was\footnote{F \label{fn:F}} \ldots

\section{Now let's cross-reference these footnotes}   
As is demonstrated in \crefrange{fn:A}{fn:F}, \ldots

\noindent
As additionally noted in \cref{fn:F,fn:A,fn:D,fn:E,fn:B}, \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Of course, the `cleveref` package's cross-referencing commands work not only with footnotes, but with just about all items that can be given a `label` -- equations, sections, figures, tables, algorithms, and so on.

Finally, be sure to have the latest version of the `cleveref` package on your system, as the package has recently been updated and upgraded significantly by its author. For instance, the `\creflastconjunction` macro that's used in the MWE probably won't work unless you have a recent version of the package.

Comment: I think that with "consecutive footnotes" the OP means several `\footnote` commands issued consecutively (without any intervening text). The `footmisc` package allows for adding a comma between the respective footnote marks.

Comment: @lockstep: OK, I may have completely misunderstood the OP's intent! Let's see what he/she has to add.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Mico. As @lockstep suggested, my question does relate to consecutive placement of multiple footnotes at the same spot, rather than subsequently cross-referencing groups of footnotes. I have amended the original post with MWEs to make this intention clear.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 1.0 (2021/01/21) `fnpct` supports ranges for multiple footnotes natively¹:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\setfnpct{ranges}
\begin{document}
This text bears a multiplicity of footnotes%
\footnote{Lorum}\footnote{ipsum}\footnote{dolor}%
\footnote{sit}\footnote{amet,}\footnote{consectetur}%
\footnote{adipisicing}\footnote{elit}
 which are referenced as one footnoterange.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

1. Credits to [Frank](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10109/) for [suggesting that feature a while back](https://github.com/cgnieder/fnpct/issues/15)