# Separating adjacent footnote labels

Tags: footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compressing consecutive footnote marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44165/compressing-consecutive-footnote-marks)

**Q:** What is the *normal* way of handling adjacent footnote labels? Do people normally go with the *first case* below?

I don't care for the *first case*. It makes footnotes one and two look like one footnote labeled `12`.

I tried fixing this and came up with *my hack* below.

**Q:** There has to be a better way of doing this, right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The first case.%
\footnote{My first footnote text}%
\footnote{My second footnote text}

My hack.%
\footnote{My third footnote text}\(^{,}\)%
\footnote{My fourth footnote text}
\end{document}
```

[image: footnotes]

Comment: It appears my question is mostly answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44165/3762). I didn't see this until after posting my question.